# Firebase auth: same (?) node.js auth workflow but for Ruby backend. How-to?

Tags: ruby, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, backend

My app consists of two parts API and now we add web app build on Hanami (Ruby).

I've added Firebase Auth in Android app, that was simple and works perfectly: once I get firebase jwt, I just use it in an auth header to request data from backend (API). Backend parse, validate it and create/update user if needed based on JWT contents. Cool!

Now we need to add authentication for traditional (not single page) web app (preserving mobile-created users of course).

And here comes the troubles.

The Firebase documentation describes workflow for SPAs and has few words about node.js support (this doesn't help anyway, see below).

Here's how I see the workflow for email/pass web auth:

1. user send email/pass to backend using form
2. server validates them
3. if they're ok, server take email/pass and sends it to Firebase somehow...
4. firebase creates user (the same way it does using android auth workflow) and return jwt with refresh_token (?)
5. server set this jwt as session HttpOnly secure cookie, and use it to identify user and subsequent requests.
6. for subsequent requests (which comes to API or web app backend, doesn't matter) all we need to do is take jwt from header (API) or session (web) and work with it as we did for API calls (parse, validate, get user object from DB based on jwt content)

The step 3, as you notice, is something I don't know how to implement.
If workflow seems right, all I need to do at backend is something like this (node.js):

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
```

But since firebasejs src is minified, I can't figure out what's happening in there to implement similar workflow in Ruby...

So, here are the questions:

- is this workflow right/possible at all?
- if not, how to solve this task?
- suppose no client-side JS possible to run, is it still possible to implement firebase auth for web client?
- is there any ruby client for helping implementing this workflow? I found this gem https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby but it seems it has nothing about authentication...
- am I got right, I don't need custom token auth here? It seems the solve different problems, like implementing not (yet) supported oauth providers, or providing custom claims.

I'm taking email/pass auth for example, but almost the same thing should be done in oauth callbacks. Like described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_manually

But this is another story :)

Any help will be very appreciated! I'm stuck here. Thanks!

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with "[mcve]". "is there any ruby client" is off-topic. Your question has too many sub-questions making it very broad. Please reduce it to one or two closely related questions.

Comment: You'll probably need to use this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens. I'm trying to solve the same problem right now.

Comment: @MatthewReilly did you have any luck with it? If so, can you briefly share your exp, please? Thanks!